# Typo on page 92 of Spivak's Calculus 4th edition?

Tags: calculus, limits

On page 92 of Spivak's calculus 4th edition in the middle of the page it states:

"We just have to be 1,000,000 times as careful, choosing $|x- a|<\epsilon/3,000,0000$ in order to ensure that $|f(x) - a|<\epsilon$."

Is it not $|f(x) - f(a)|<\epsilon$ or $|f(x) - l|<\epsilon$?

Can it be a tiny typo or I am missing the point? Any clarification on this is very much appreciated.

Comment: Looks like a typo. from here, but I don't have the book here.

Comment: [Spivak](http://www.mathpop.com/) includes an [errata of the 4th edition](https://pctex.org/mathpop/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/cal4errata2-4.pdf). Through looking at a PDF, I could not find the error on page 92.

Comment: I will take it as a typo and move on...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is about the continuity of the function $ f $ at the point $ x=a $, it will be $$|f(x)-f(a)|<\epsilon$$

If it is about the limit of $ f $ at $ x=a $, it will be $$|f(x)-l|<\epsilon$$
and in this case, $$\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=l.$$

Comment: I just finished the chapter and indeed it is clearly: $|f(x) - l|<\epsilon$.